# Dimension formula proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I got stuck understanding the proof from [here](http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2013/2631/39/LA-4-12.pdf) (page 1, last line).

Why is $z \in X \cap Y$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the same last line, $z$ is expressed onece as a linear combination  of vectors in $X$ and once as a linear combination of vetcors in$Y$.

Comment: thanks! it makes sense now :)